# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{n}g(x)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{n}g(x) dx = 0$$ where $g$ is in $L^2$ space.

How to prove it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i used holder ineq. but it doesn't work...

Comment: Well, before Holder, have you try one of its special cases -- Cauchy-Schwartz? (if so, *what* did not work?)

Comment: Yes. i used  Cauchy-Schwartz(holder for p=2). If we used  Cauchy-Schwartz ineq, we don't have anything. Is my opinion false?..

Comment: *What* did you obtain in doing so -- why is it not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^{1/n}g(x)\,dx\right|^2 &\le \int_0^{1/n}g^2(x)\,dx\int_0^{1/n}1\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{1/n}g^2(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{n}\int_0^{1/n}g(x)\,dx\right| &\le \sqrt{\int_0^{1/n}g^2(x)\,dx}\\\\
&\to 0
\end{align}$$

as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I showed this before uploading question. But I had forgot that Lebesgue integration on measure zero set is always zero.

Comment: @YSRiemann  You're welcome.  My pleasure.  It's always nice to be able to help!